# How can I create separate PouchDBs on separate endpoints in the same Node app, living in separate databases on disk?

Tags: node.js, express, pouchdb

Express-pouchdb, part of [Pouchdb-server](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb-server#express-pouchdb), is a "fully qualified Express application" that creates a mostly-CouchDB-compliant database in Node that allows browser-based PouchDB instances to sync to it.

My goal is to have Node create *multiple separate* PouchDBs, on separate endpoints, that store their data in totally different paths on disk.

After running `npm install express-pouchdb pouchdb express`, I start with the snippet from the docs: one endpoint, one PouchDB—

```js
var PouchDB = require('pouchdb');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use('/db1', require('express-pouchdb')(PouchDB));
app.listen(3000);
```

This of course works fine.

However, adapting this to add a second endpoint fails:

```js
// same setup as above
app.use('/db1', require('express-pouchdb')(PouchDB));
app.use('/db2', require('express-pouchdb')(PouchDB));
app.listen(3000);
```

Node immediately encounters `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: [object Object]`. I can `curl localhost:3000/db1` successfully but `curl localhost:3000/db2` just hangs.

I try the following to create separate PouchDB instances:

```js
// same setup as above
app.use(
    '/db3', require('express-pouchdb')(new PouchDB('db3', {prefix: 'db3/'})));
app.use(
    '/db4', require('express-pouchdb')(new PouchDB('db4', {prefix: 'db4/'})));
app.listen(3000);
```

Node will happily start, but when I `curl localhost:3000/db3`, Node throws: `Error: express-pouchdb needs a PouchDB object to route a request!`. I thought I gave it a PouchDB object though?

How do people run multiple PouchDBs in the same Node app with express-pouchdb?

(My end-goal is to have a separate PouchDB for each Passport.js-authenticated user. I don't want to use Pouch/Couch auth since there appear to be [security issues](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb-server/issues/415) in PouchDB-Server. And I want them to live in separate directories on the disk for isolation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's helpful to think of the express app as being an *actual* CouchDB instance.  From that perspective, consider how one creates a new database with CouchDB<sup>1</sup>:

```
curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/{db_name}
```

From this perspective there is no need to create distinct PouchDB's for every database instance, rather create the databases as one would for CouchDB.

This code simply spins up a server, placing all database files in a sub-directory<sup>2</sup>

```
const express = require("express"),
  app = express(),
  PouchDB = require("pouchdb");
// In the current directory, place all database files into a directory named 'database'
const configPouchDB = PouchDB.defaults({ prefix: "./database/" });
app.use("/", require("express-pouchdb")(configPouchDB));
app.listen(3000);
```

From the shell, fire up the server

```
$ node app.js
```

And from another shell, hit the default endpoint and we see the response is just CouchDB-like

```
$ curl localhost:3000
{"express-pouchdb":"Welcome!","version":"4.2.0","pouchdb-adapters":["leveldb"],"vendor":{"name":"PouchDB authors","version":"4.2.0"},"uuid":"00739d7f-3b78-4a73-b69c-0af98bd819e7"}
```

Now that the server is running create databases as one may with CouchDB

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:3000/db1
{"ok":true}

curl -X PUT http://localhost:3000/db2
{"ok":true}
```

Now if it is absolutely required to have specific pouchDB instances in the server code you *could* do the following (for this example code, delete the database directory first to demonstrate creation)

```
const express = require("express"),
  app = express(),
  PouchDB = require("pouchdb");
// In the current directory, place all database files into a directory named 'database'
const configPouchDB = PouchDB.defaults({ prefix: "./database/" });
app.use("/", require("express-pouchdb")(configPouchDB));
app.listen(3000);
//
// create databases now 
//
const dbs = {
  db1: new PouchDB("db1"),
  db2: new PouchDB("db2"),
};
```

After the server fires up, curl will show the databases are created on startup.

```
$ curl localhost:3000/db1
{"doc_count":0,"update_seq":0,"backend_adapter":"LevelDOWN","db_name":"db1","auto_compaction":false,"adapter":"leveldb","disk_size":198,"instance_start_time":"1601040439637"}  

$ curl localhost:3000/db2
{"doc_count":0,"update_seq":0,"backend_adapter":"LevelDOWN","db_name":"db2","auto_compaction":false,"adapter":"leveldb","disk_size":197,"instance_start_time":"1601040439637"}
```

**Update**
I understand your use case better now after reading your comment.  Consider this

```
const express = require("express"),
  app = express(),
  PouchDB = require("pouchdb");
// In the current directory, place all database files into a directory named 'database'
const configPouchDB = PouchDB.defaults({ prefix: "./database/" });
const db = require("express-pouchdb")(configPouchDB);

app.use("/", (req, res) => {
  // this simply delegates the request.
  // here you can add conditional logic.
  db(req, res);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

I recommend reading up on Express Middleware<sup>3</sup> and Express Router<sup>4</sup>, the latter of which may provide efficient solutions.

1. [Create a CouchDB database](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/common.html#put--db)
2. [Express-PouchDB defaults](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb-server#pouchdb-defaults)
3. [Express Middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html#writing-middleware-for-use-in-express-apps)
4. [Express Router](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router)

Comment: Is there no way to place Express middleware in front of requests to `/db1` and `/db2`? I'd love to use Passport auth to control access to these endpoints but it looks like the Express app owns the entire `/` endpoint so I can't put middleware inside it (without hacking express-pouchdb).

Comment: I've amended my answer with clarifications regarding middleware. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks to your patient and cogent explanation I was able to put together a substantial proof-of-concept: https://gist.github.com/fasiha/df973540790923c3392d1e6e94990d59 thank you!